# Unexpected class type for object created using 'insertNewObjectForEntityForName'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have two different objects which I create using `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` using the same context.
My problem is that for the first object, `Event`, the object type is correctly defined as `Event`, while for the second object which should be of type `Credit`, the object type is instead `NSManagedObject` (which means I can't called methods defined in the derived class on it).

**Object 1:** (as expected)

```
Event *event = (Event*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:context];

(gdb) po event
<Event: 0x62b3f00> (entity: Event; id: 0x62b3fb0 <x-coredata:///Event/tD3B27884-D303-4FDE-9D0F-D7DC009E2EBB18> ; data: {
...
})
```

**Object 2:** (expected class to be `Credit` and not `NSManagedObject`)

```
Credit *credit = (Credit*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Credit" inManagedObjectContext:context];

(gdb) po credit
<NSManagedObject: 0x629fd50> (entity: Credit; id: 0x628caf0 <x-coredata:///Credit/tD3B27884-D303-4FDE-9D0F-D7DC009E2EBB36> ; data: {
...
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you've double-checked that the entity is indeed mapped to the `Credit` class in the model editor?

Comment: damn - the editor... I had mapped it to "Credits" by mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you don't get any sort of warning if you miss it. One way to ensure it's always right (aside from tests, obviously) is to generate the classes from the model in the model editor.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a custom class name assigned for the entity in the data model so the context just returns a generic managed object instance. Right now it just says, "NSManagedObject" instead of "Credit".